# HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated throwing System.NullReferenceException

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Why is `HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` throwing `System.NullReferenceException` in the base controller from where all my other controllers are inheriting from?

I think the `HttpContext` is not ready inside the constructor of my base controller.

This is the code:

```cs
public abstract class BasicController : Controller
{
    private IUserProfileRepository _userProfileRepository;

    protected BasicController()
        : this(new UserProfileRepository())
    {
    }

    protected BasicController(IUserProfileRepository userProfileRepository)
    {
        _userProfileRepository = userProfileRepository;
        if (HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            var user = _userProfileRepository.Getuser(HttpContext.User.Identity.Name);
            ViewData["currentlyLoggedInUser"] = user;
        }
        else
        {
            ViewData["currentlyLoggedInUser"] = null;
        }
    }
```

### Solution

`HttpContext` was not ready in the base controller constructor. So this is what I did, now it's working fine:

```cs
public abstract class BasicController : Controller
{
    private IUserProfileRepository _userProfileRepository;

    protected BasicController()
        : this(new UserProfileRepository())
    {
    }

    protected BasicController(IUserProfileRepository userProfileRepository)
    {
        _userProfileRepository = userProfileRepository;
    }

    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            var user = _userProfileRepository.Getuser(filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name);
            filterContext.Controller.ViewData["currentlyLoggedInUser"] = user;
        }
        else
        {
            filterContext.Controller.ViewData["currentlyLoggedInUser"] = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for posting the solution to the problem after fixing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because *HttpContext.User* has not been set by any authentication module. Are you requiring authenticated users for this site? Did you disable the *DefaultAuthenticationModule*? Or perhaps the controller instance is created before the [AuthenticateRequest event of *HttpApplication*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.authenticaterequest.aspx) is fired?

Comment: Yes, I need authentication for this site. I have used "HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated" at other places in my code and it works fine

Comment: And you have <authorization><allow users="?" /></authorization> or similar in your web.config?

Comment: Then it is likely that the controller instance is created before the `AuthenticateRequest` event happens.

Comment: Yes thats what even I think..is there someway i can get it some how??

Comment: Nice! I was writing a comment to suggest something like that.